# Difference between "which are you" and "which you are"

Tags: difference, interrogatives, subject-auxiliary-inversion

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> 1. Which bike are you using?
> 2. Which bike you are using?

Answer (score 3):

The first one is a question but should include a question mark:

Which bike are you using?

The second one is incorrect as written but could form part of a correct sentence:

I want to know which bike you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: [verb 'be' in different tenses](http://www.learnamericanenglishonline.com/Yellow%20Level/Y28_Be.html)

In order to form questions, you simply need to interchange the first two words of the constructions given in the chart(refer to the link) and then complete the question as you wish. This works well for all the constructions that have been mentioned.

For ex: 'I was...' ==> 'Was I...?' (statement==>question)

The correct answer is a direct result of the explanation given above. You need to use 'Which bike **are you** using?'. If you interchange the two, you will find that the result is a part of a statement(Tell me the name of the bike that **you are** using.)

I cannot tell you the difference between the two options that you've provided because the second one is wrong. I can only state which one is correct and how the interchange works.

Pay close attention to the punctuation marks as well.
Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

This is a question (or specifically interrogative sentence).

**Question:**

> *Are you* a boy?

**Sentence:**

> *You are* a boy.

---

So if you just switched the verb/subject, the sentence will be question/sentence.

---

Now let us look at a longer sentence.

**Question:**

> Which bike *are you* using?
>
> Which bike *you are* using?

**Sentence:**

> *You are* using a bike.

Thus, the first sentence is correct and the second sentence is grammatically wrong.

Conclusively, *you are* is a sentence while *are you* is a question.

Same goes for other types:

> *Is this* helpful?
>
> *This is* helpful.